# Java: Receives three numbers (short, int, long), the method must RETURN the largest number

Tags: java

Basically my method must receive three different data types (`short, int, long`) and display the largest. However the method cannot translate them because I am using `char`, that is obvious but I don't know what else to use instead, I need a different way for cast those objects using 'return'.

Error msg: method in class cannot be applied to given types. Required: short, int, long

And yes, I need to use Swing library...

```
package homework;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class test {
    String result = null;

public static int addnumber(String title, String message){
    return JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, title,message, -1).charAt(0); 
}
public static void largest(short a, int b, long c) {

    if (a > b) {
        System.out.println(a + " Is the largest number");
    } else if (a > c) {
        System.out.println(a + " Is the largest number");
    } else if (b > a) {
        System.out.println(b + " Is the largest number");
    } else if (b > c) {
        System.out.println(b + " Is the largest number");
    } else if (c > a) {
        System.out.println(c + " Is the largest number");
    } else if (c > b) {
        System.out.println(c + " Is the largest number");
    }

    else {
        System.out.println("wrong number");
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
   largest(addnumber(
    "Number", "Add number")); 

}

public test() {
}

}
```

Comment: What's the problem with this code? Please, describe the problem or post the error message as precisely as possible.

Comment: Error msg: method in class cannot be applied to given types. Required: short, int, long

Comment: This is because you aren't passing these data types to largest method. Make sure you are accepting 3 numbers of those data types first and then call that method

Comment: Your method is expecting three variables, so you need to prompt/enter three numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it sounds like you main trouble is getting the values from the JOptionPane. First you shouldn't be using charAt, because that will just give you the value of the character. Which wouldn't be the number you type.

```
public static int addnumber(String title, String message){
    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, title,message, -1);
    return Integer.parseInt(input); 
}
```

That will give you one value for each JOptionPane.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   short a = (short)addNumber("Enter numbers", "short value");
   int b = addNumber("Enter numbers", "int value");
   long c = addNumber(Enter numbers", "long value");
   largest(a,b,c);
}
```

From there you can fix your largest method to actually print the largest.

Comment: Thanks!!! this works perfectly! Just my logic in the If statement is wrong because given 3 numbers (1,2,3) it's returning that the number 2 is the largest, but that is my logic issue. I will try to fix it. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Pass your variable like this `largest((short)22,14,6);`
and replace your logic with

```
public static int largest(short a, int b, long c) {

    if (a > b) {
        if (a > c) {
            return a;
        } else
            return (int) c;
    } else {
        if (b > c)
            return b;
        else
            return (int) c;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, yeap this works but I need to request the 3 numbers using "JOptionPane". although my professor only requested use if\if else and return the largest number of short, int, long data types...

Comment: @KarenD can you make 3 JOptionPanes appear? Or do you want all the values from one?

Comment: Also, this doesn't return the "largest".

Comment: ` public static int largest(short a, int b, long c) {
return (int)(a>b?a:b>c?b:c);

 }`

Comment: Nope. Think about what happens if a = 2 b=1 and c=3.

Comment: aren't you allowed to use  ternary operator?

Comment: Okay. that was my mistake .. please check now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182698/discussion-between-manishnegi-and-matt).

Answer (score 0):

Don't think casting is an issue.  Give this a try:

```
private static void largest(short a, int b, long c) {
  if (a > b && a > c)
    System.out.println(a + " Is the largest number");
  else if (b > c)
    System.out.println(b + " Is the largest number");
  else
    System.out.println(c + " Is the largest number");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the correct logic for the IF statement.